# How to tag CloudWatch custom metrics generated by ECS Container Insights?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

While CloudWatch custom metrics from [EC2 detailed monitoring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-cloudwatch-new.html) inherit [tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/tag-editor/latest/userguide/tagging.html) from the source EC2 instance, those from [ECS Container Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ContainerInsights.html) do not inherit tags from ECS services, at least not by default. I would like to have tags in order to help categorize CloudWatch costs. Is there any way to enable inheriting them from ECS or add them somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the answer to this as well and asked this question on re:Post and got the following response:

"Metrics are not AWS resources, and as such they cannot be tagged. When you navigate to Cost Explorer and break down your CloudWatch detailed monitoring costs by tag, a special treatment is applied to EC2, which is not applicable to resources from other services." - jsc on AWS re:Post

In short, this would take an enhancement from AWS which can only happen through community attention or feature requests from support cases.

Link to full re:Post answer - https://repost.aws/questions/QUM_42KlyIR26jC36xYr6WcQ/how-to-tag-cloudwatch-custom-metrics-generated-by-ecs-container-insights

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! It would surely be a useful change to support it though, since modern applications use more ECS than EC2 unless they are on EKS, but I think ECS is much simpler and there are many cases when it is enough.

Comment: I agree. Maybe if we both open up feature requests for this, we could get the ball rolling on it...

Comment: I agree, I have sent them a support request from the console and upvoted your post. If you have access to enterprise support or similar, I also recommend opening a support case (based on this: https://cloudar.be/awsblog/tips-for-making-aws-feature-requests/).